# Class ZMQContext not found even though ZMQ is installed

Tags: php, apache

First of all, yes I am aware that there is a very similar question out there, but the answer given there doesn't apply to my situation, and there's no indication that it fixed the other person's problem either.

I have ZMQ installed on my Apache server, according to the tutorial found in the Racthet documentation. I installed everything successfully after a lot of frustration, and I am ready to run an example. The simple PHP script is placed in `post.php` and features this line (after some rather trivial PHP, setting variables etc):

```
$context = new ZMQContext();
```

However, it throws this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'ZMQContext' not found in /home/lights/public_html/apps/post.php on line 12
```

I have included `extension=zmq.so` at the end of my *only* used php.ini file, as the zeromq documentation suggested. To make sure Apache is loading the same php.ini as the page, I checked. Apache gave me exactly the same info as running phpinfo() on the page:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File   /usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

From this I concluded that the same error should appear if I run `php post.php` from the terminal. However, no error was shown in this case - it seems the PHP code did its part. So, I have eliminated the only possible root cause that I have found in my search so far, and I am looking for an alternative.

Anyone have a solution, suggestion, idea, anything at all that could help clear this up?

Comment: If you call `phpinfo()` in the same file as you call `new ZMQContext()`, does the output show ZeroMQ is loaded (in the "Configuration" section)?

Comment: `ZMQContext` belongs to the root namespace. In order to avoid any confusion and possible errors, it's the best to create the context using `$ctx = new \ZMQContext();`. That way you can eliminate one possible mistake. If that doesn't work, you can try hunting for other possible errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the extension is enabled you still need to use this:

```
use \ZMQContext;
use \ZMQ;
```

(or alternatively directly access them using a leading "\")

Comment: FYI Not sure what version of PHP you were using, but with PHP 8.1 in 2022 this produces "Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'ZMQContext' has no effect" so I think this is pointless.

Answer (score 5):

I have not used ZMQ but this seems like a configure problem.

#### First, run PHP in cli and in apache can use different php.ini

Eg in ubuntu 12.04:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini is used for apache
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini is used for cli
```

To check if ZMQ is currently loaded in apache, create a php file contains `phpinfo();` and check it's output through web browser, there should be some info about ZMQ, use ctrl-f to search for it.

In cli, `php -m` will show loaded/compiled module or extension.

#### Second, ZMQ version

I can't thought other reason than you used a ZMQ version which hasn't ZMQContext ? You could check ZMQ document and the version you used.

#### (Deleted, should not be this problem according error message), namespace

if ZMQ is currectly loaded, and your code still doesn't work, the another possible reason is use of namespace. If your post.php is like

```
<?php
namespace Some\NameSpace;
$context = new ZMQContext();
```

Then it means ZMQContext in namespace Some\NameSpace, the full quanlified classname is Some\NameSpace\ZMQContext, which doesn't exists. So you may need use `\ZMQContext` for class out of current namespace.

Comment: I have eliminated options 1 and 3 (checked configuration and made sure I have the latest version of ZMQ). I'm not sure I understand option #2, can you clarify with some more detail?

Comment: Namespaces are not the issue here, because PHP complains about `ZMQContext`, not `Some\NameSpace\ZMQContext`.

Comment: @jovan If you have latest verion of ZMQ, suggested to check #1 through phpinfo();

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart Apache before using new extensions. mod_php doesn't add modules during runtime

Answer (score -2):

If you use Wampserver, copy `libzmq.dll` file into `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\bin` and restart wamp.