# Fatal error: Class 'ZMQ' not found in index.php on line 6

Tags: php, wamp, zeromq

I've just installed ZMQ, followed the tutorial for Windows, everythings works. Except the fact that I cannot create object of ZMQContext because ZMQ class in the parameter is not defined.

```
  $context = new ZMQContext(1);
  $publisher = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_PUB); //ZMQ is not defined.
```

The ZMQ class doesn't exist in the API at all... how can I initialise this?

Extra info:

I got this DLL: php_zmq-1.1.2-5.6-ts-vc11-x86  from windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/zmq/1.1.2

Wampserver is also x86

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class ZMQContext not found even though ZMQ is installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252657/class-zmqcontext-not-found-even-though-zmq-is-installed)

Comment: @User8889 ZMQContext is found for me...

Comment: Which ZMQ extension version did you install? Also, just to rule weird things out, can you try using `$publisher = $context->getSocket(\ZMQ::SOCKET_PUB);` to check what happens?

Comment: @By ZMQ extension you mean the dll? If so: php_zmq-1.1.2-5.6-ts-vc11-x86 from http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/zmq/1.1.2/

Comment: @N.B. Can you explain me where ZMQ gets defined in the \ZMQ::SOCKET_PUB?

Comment: `ZMQ` is just a class that contains a few constants, if you're asking what slash(\) does in front of ZMQ, it just says that it's the root namespace. I'm not using Windows so I can't really say what's wrong. Have you tried to compile the extension using source from github or you just downloaded a .dll? It might be an older version where the `ZMQ` doesn't exist or something like that.

Comment: @N.B.But the ZMQ class doesn't even exist in the api.php of ZMQ. https://github.com/mkoppanen/php-zmq/blob/644fa8e98760905beff6ff96c569365c57f3e69c/api.php