# Uncaught Error: Class 'ZMQContext' not found

Tags: php, apache, zeromq

I've seen [Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252657/class-zmqcontext-not-found-even-though-zmq-is-installed), [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38054563/class-zmqcontext-not-found), None of these Helped,

I'm seeing this error for 2 days,
I've set `libzmq.dll` and `php_zmq.dll` in correct place, I don't see ZMQ in `phpinfo()` and also when using `ZMQContext()` seeing error as below:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ZMQContext' not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\blog\process_create.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\blog\process_create.php on line 21
```

Answer (score 0):

If your server is ubuntu.

```
$ sudo apt-get install pkg-config
$ sudo apt-get install autotools-dev
$ sudo apt-get install autoconf

$ git clone git://github.com/zeromq/libzmq.git
$ cd libzmq/
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure && make
$ sudo make install

$ git clone git://github.com/mkoppanen/php-zmq.git
$ cd php-zmq/
$ phpize
$ ./configure && make
$ sudo make install

$ sudo echo "extension=zmq.so" >> /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

You can copy example pubsub php from "Pub-Sub envelope subscriber in PHP"

http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:psenvpub

http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:psenvsub

Oops.. you are using windows.. I noticed right now.

Comment: As of now I'm testing it with Local Windows machine.